# Save An Array numpy to a `.csv` file using filedialog

Tags: python, numpy, csv, filedialog

i Have an array of (200rows x 4 columns) and i want to save it into a `.csv` file i used the function savetxt()
`np.savetxt("myfile.csv", np.column_stack([time_axis[::1], outputdataEz[::1], outputdataHx[::1], outputdataHy[::1]]), delimiter=',   ', fmt = '%1.50f')`

and when I check the `.csv` file I found that all my data was successfully saved into a `.csv` File.

And now I want to use the same operation but using FileDialog: asksaveasfile as you can see in my code bellow

`result = np.column_stack([time_axis[::1], outputdataEz[::1], outputdataHx[::1], outputdataHy[::1]])`

`print(result.shape)`

`print(result)`

`result = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".csv")`

When I check my file I found it empty.
Any suggestions, please.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You aren't calling savetxt in the second snippet. The dialog just returns a name

Comment: Oh yes you are right i got it, thank you

Comment: If that fixed it, please feel free to delete the question, as it's based on a simple omission